# jquery sortable javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a nested set of objects I would like to sort.  The first example, directly below, is my prototype / test.  It works nicely.  The outer groups sort, and the inner groups sort. the inner groups are locked inside - cant be moved outside.  Just exactly like i want...

```
<div id="example5">
    <ul class="table">
        <li class="group" style="width:300px;">Group 1
            <ul style="padding:0px;">
                <li class="field">Group 2</li>
                <li class="field">Group 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="group">Group 2</li>
        <li class="group">Group 3</li>
        <li class="group">Group 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And

```
$("#example5 ul").sortable({

});
```

This is the same structure I am trying to impart in my program.  Everything seems the same to me, just with some added complexity.  Clearly, I am breaking it somehow.  The outer groups sort, while the inner ones do not.

I think its important to note that in the previous example, the script and html are in the same file.  In the second example, below, the html is dynamically created with createElement() function

```
<div id="logtable">
    <ul id="ultable" class="table ui-sortable">
        <li id="" class="groupcontainer" style="width:auto; margin:2px;">
            <ul>
                <li class="fieldcontainer">
                    <div class="fieldname"></div>
                    <div class="fieldgroup"></div>
                    <div class="fieldname"></div>
                    <div class="fieldname"></div>
                    <div class="fieldname"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="a" class="groupcontainer" style="margin: 2px;"></li>
        <li class="groupcontainer" style="margin: 2px;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var fieldstart;
    var fieldend;
    $("#logtable ul").sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) { 
            fieldstart = ui.item.index();   
        },
        update: function(event, ui) { 
            fieldend = ui.item.index();
            var fieldcount = jsonstring.tracelog.fields.length;
            var fieldobjects = jsonstring.tracelog.fields;
            var placed = false;

            jsonstring.tracelog.fields.move(fieldstart, fieldend);

            writejson();    
        }
    });
});
```

Following up, this site... http://www.trace-log.com/sortworks.php is copied from the "inspect element" output. it works exactly like i want. http://www.trace-log.com is the site i generated it from.  basically, add a value to the field name, it will generate a new field.  entering a value in the first text box will initiate the "grouping" of fields.  cant understand why this isn't working.

so as it stands, it works if i statically recreate the page, but doesnt work correctly on the dynamically created page.  could it be somehow with the way the sortable function is being called?

Comment: and the logtable div IS closed out.  Not showing up here for some reason.

Comment: Are you executing the `sortable` call after the "container" elements are created?

Comment: yes. in the example, the elements div "logtable" and ul "ultable" are html.  Everything else is created. After the elements are created, at the very end of the linked file, is the sortable function.

Comment: There must be something else wrong with your code. The following fiddle shows that dynamically adding elements or containers works. http://jsfiddle.net/4Mk4K/2/

Answer (score 0):

In the second example the field container is an `li` and the field names are `div` tags. The first example you had the field container as an `ul` tag and the fields as `li`. I think this might be your issue.

see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4Mk4K/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a custom class to the elements you want to be sortable and then use that class in the `items` option of sortable.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/161/

HTML:

```
<div id="logtable">
    <ul id="ultable" class="table ui-sortable">
        <li id="" class="groupcontainer item" style="width:auto; margin:2px;">Z
            <ul>
                <li class="fieldcontainer">
                    <div class="fieldname item">A</div>
                    <div class="fieldgroup item">B</div>
                    <div class="fieldname item">C</div>
                    <div class="fieldname item">D</div>
                    <div class="fieldname item">E</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="a" class="groupcontainer item" style="margin: 2px;">F</li>
        <li class="groupcontainer item" style="margin: 2px;">G</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var fieldstart;
    var fieldend;
    $("#logtable ul").sortable({
        items: '.item',//Custom class of items which needs to be sorted.
        start: function (event, ui) {
            fieldstart = ui.item.index();
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks kamlesh.  I tried the custom item.  For some reason it works on the li element instead of the ul element - and the behavior is bizarre.  I added a couple of links to the question showing a working model created from static html, and a link to the dynamically creatable table

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling and fussing, relocating the sortable function into the function that creates the DOM objects solved the problem.  I think the way it was originally structured, some DOM objects were created AFTER the sortable function - and sortable didn't know they existed.

So yes, there was something else structurally wrong with my code.  Thanks everyone for the help.